# My answer was deleted for no reason!

Tags: discussion

[How to add a keyboard modifier state applet to Unity panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/402315/how-to-add-a-keyboard-modifier-state-applet-to-unity-panel) explains how a moderator uses his power to delete true answers. You can check it!!

Comment: Above 10k users and moderators will be able to answer this question.

Answer (score 6):

1) Your answer was not correct.
2) Placing accept please in the answer is bad form.  If a user says "Thanks... that fixed it" then a response comment of "How about the check" or whatever might be appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

Answers are suppose to be descriptive, and give detailed information of how to solve the issue.  Try to add more information that can be helpful to the OP and other users who may have the same issue.  For more information take a look at [Answering](https://askubuntu.com/help/answering)